# Passing array between objects in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and came across a problem passing an array from a class to the other. Suppose I have two classes, one to draw a curve, and another one to draw its FT, as shown below:

```
Tangle.classes.RFPulse = {

  initialize: function(el,options,tangle) {
    this.tangle = tangle;
    this.RFSincShape = [];
  },
  update: function(el, pulseDuration) {
    ....
    for (x=0; x < canvasWidth; x++) {
    this.RFSincShape[x] = x;
  },
  getSincCurve: function() {
    return this.RFSincShape; // Something wrong here?
  }
}

Tangle.classes.RFPulseFT = {

  initialize: function (el,options,tangle) {
     this.tangle = tangle;
     // or something wrong here?
     this.SliceShape = Tangle.classes.RFPulse.getSincCurve();
  },

  update: function (el,c_timeBandwidthProduct, c_pulseDuration) {
     // or here?
     this.SliceShape = Tangle.classes.RFPulse.getSincCurve();
     ... FFT of this.SliceShape...
  }
}
```

Why is it that I can't retrieve the RFSincShape? How could I solve the problem, and what is good practice for these issues?

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to `.initialize` `Tangle.classes.RFPulse` before using it.

Comment: it is initialised first, since I can see all other variables from RFPulse exist. But thanks for the observation

Comment: If I change `getSincCurve` to return 3, instead of an array, then I can retrieve the value without problems.

Comment: Inside `RFPulseFT` you don't invoke `initialize` method that's why you get `undefined`. Please look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4g6a9ug/1/)